# Knitr utf8 \u20ac replaced by \u0080

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, latex, knitr

I'm using Rstudio on windows and have problems using utf characters in Rnw file:

When using knitr on Rnw file, utf character \u20ac (euro symbol) is replaced in tex file by \u0080. Rnw file contains:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{\euro}
\begin{document}
<<print, echo = FALSE>>=
x <- '\U20AC'
Encoding(x)
print(x)
sessionInfo()
@
\end{document}
```

resulting in tex file (last lines only):

```
\begin{verbatim}
## [1] "UTF-8"
## [1] "<U+0080>"
## R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
## Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
## Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
## 
## locale:
## [1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252   
## [3] LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
## [5] LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## other attached packages:
## [1] knitr_1.14.1
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
## [1] magrittr_1.5  formatR_1.4   tools_3.3.0   stringi_1.1.1 stringr_1.1.0
## [6] evaluate_0.9
\end{verbatim}
```

command used:

```
knitr('test.Rnw')
```

Resulting tex file cannot be processed by latex:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char Â (U+80)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Using sweave instead of knitr works fine.